# Should something be shown in the timeline at the start for an event with a start/end?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, developer-story

When looking through a user's events chronologically I find it a bit tricky to build up a picture in my head of what the user's story is regarding events with a start and end. Where there are some early events then a later event (e.g. a job) that started before some of the earlier events it's displayed above because it ended after them.

What do people think about displaying something (not necessarily duplicating the event, maybe just a one line link) to indicate when an event with a beginning and end started?

Comment: Maybe if something is shown, it's only shown where there are events between the start and end dates.

Comment: We're currently looking into giving users the flexibility to group or highlight items. This will improve the readability of the timeline.